# Problem with Table of content numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I am using following commands to create a Table of Contents

```
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}

\section{Introduction} %% first section
```

Table of contents generated is like this

[image]

How do I make it `1` instead of `0.1`.

Comment: I guess you're using the `report` class and no `\chapter` command.

Comment: Yes, i am using report class, but I need '1' instead of 0.1.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}`

Comment: @user147798: What's the request for `0.2.1`?  Is it `1.2.1` then? Please post a MWE. If you have no chapters, `report` has virtually no advantages, you could use `article` then, with less efforts

Comment: No, it is 2.1. And thanks for your suggestion using article works.

Comment: Off-topic comment: You've asked some questions, each has upvoted answers, so please consider to accept one of them

Answer (score 2):

Switching to `article` class will remove the 'wrong' formatting of section numbers if no `\chapter` is used.

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}  % Why?

\section{Introduction} %% first section
\section{Materials and Methods}
\subsection{Soil samples and study area}
\subsubsection{Further Reading}
\section{Results and Discussion}



\end{document}
```